# localization fails with strongly typed resources in web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, localization, webforms, strong-typing

We've created two Resource files GlobalResources.resx (English) and GlobalResources.de.resx (German).

This works (text is translated to language based on web browser setting):

```
string s = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResources",
    "YouHaveSuccessfullyLoggedOut");
```

This does not (text is always English):

```
string s = Resources.GlobalResources.YouHaveSuccessfullyLoggedOut;
```

Why?

Comment: There are states that we souldn't ask questions... I salute you just because you managed to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

It's now working again.

We think it may have happened because the application was running (in Debug), or the .resx file was open (in an VS Editor window) when we re-factored the string into a resource (using http://resourcerefactor2010.codeplex.com/). It's to do with when VS decides to generate the .designer files (we've even seen it create two .designer files for one .resx file) - this whole area is flaky in VS2010 and needs be treated gently!